# spring get basicDBObject element using element index within size()

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, spring-data

I have a list of string in my BasicDBObject

> ```
>   "key_elements": [ "0125", "0120", "0655"]
> ```

and would like to get the Strings using the `BasicDBOject.size()` information. I expected to use the bellow code but it doesn't compile:

```
keyElementsList = new ArrayList<String>();

BasicDBObject keySetDBO = (BasicDBObject)basicDBObject.get("key_elements");
for (int i = 0; i < keySetDBO.size(); ++i){
    keyElementsList.add((String)keySetDBO.getString(i));
}
```

but I have a compilation error on `keySetDBO.getString(i)`! I've tried also `keySetDBO[i]` but it also doesn't work! Any Idea of how to best realize the `keyElementList`?

Comment: what is 'basicDBObject' ?

Comment: the basicDBObject was a retrieved document from mongoDB. In such document there was the 'key_elements' array i tried to retrieve from basicDBObject. Casting the result to BasicDBList i reached the goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a basic error in question above: the key_element

> "key_elements": [ "0125", "0120", "0655"]

cannot be cast to com.mongodb.BasicDBObject but is castable to com.mongodb.BasicDBList, with this last class exposed the get(i) where i is the index within BasicDBList.size(). the code looks as follow:

```
List<String> keyElementList = new ArrayList<String>;

BasicDBList bDBList = (BasicDBList)basicDBObject.get("key_elements");

for(int i = 0; i < bDBList.size(); ++i){
    keyElementsList.add((String)bDBList.get(i));
}
```

using BasicDBObject the access to information is by the mean of key get from keySet() method.

Comment: Effectivelly it was a BasicDBList that i was looking for. Casting the result of the retrieved array from the initial basicDBObject i reached the goal.